# cannot connect to aurora postgresql

Tags: postgresql, connection, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

the connection always shows "Operation timed out."

[aurora postgresql configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T777u.png)

I create a aurora postgresql cluster, set all traffic to the security inbound/outbound, Publicly accessible also set yes, but still cannot connect to database.

Im not sure if there is any configration that i missed to set?

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't create an internet gateway, you should create an internet gateway from VPC service and attach it to your VPC. Then you can associate it with the subnet where you placed the Aurora PostgreSQL through a route table. The subnet becomes a public subnet and you can access Aurora PostgreSQL in the subnet. Please see this link for the configuration. https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/aurora-mysql-connect-outside-vpc